# QR code how to display in Angular Nativescript App

Tags: nativescript, qr-code, angular2-nativescript

Found a lot of examples for QR code scanner functionality but couldn't find any that are about displaying QR Code. Not sure how this can be done as nativesript is using specific xml based controls. Seems you can't build UI with something different than these. How to solve this problem. Also I want the visualisation of the QR code to be working in offline mode. Thanks!

Comment: I have not used this plugin but it has the ability to create QR codes https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-zxing. It looks pretty straightforward, by creating an Image that you can then display as you would any other Image.

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev If my answer solved your question please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to display a QR code using @NathanaelA 's nativescript-plugin ([nativescript-zxing](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-zxing)) mentioned in the comment above:

```
import * as imgSource from "tns-core-modules/image-source";

const ZXing = require('nativescript-zxing');

const zx = new ZXing();
const barcode = zx.createBarcode({encode: "Text", height: 100, width: 100, format: ZXing.QR_CODE});
```

Return value `barcode` is either an `android.graphics.Bitmap` if running on Android or an `UIImage` if running on iOS.

```
img.imageSource = imgSource.fromNativeSource(barcode);
```

Use the native image instance appropriately. Here `img` is an nativescript [Image widget](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/images) and `imgSource` is the nativescript class [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source). You set the imageSource attribute of the Image widget with the result of fromNativeSource method offered by the ImageSource instance.

Generally, you can mostly find examples of how to use a plugin in the demo folder of their repository.

Kind regards,
David